# Jquery is not working on IE8

Tags: jquery, wordpress

jQuery Tabs is not working on IE8 - Working fine on FF/Safari/Chrome/ie7
For tab control, I am using
Java script: -

```
<?php
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery-cycle', get_bloginfo('template_directory')  .'/js/jquery.cycle.js',array('jquery','jquery-ui-core','jquery-ui-tabs')); 
?>
```

in wordpress and using this

```
jQuery("#tabs").tabs();
```

to call tabs.

help me why its not working on IE8

Comment: because its IE - does it really need a reason

Comment: Post a link. You haven't given enough info

Comment: Have you tried any firebugging?

Answer (score 0):

It's a CSS bug more than likely. IE8 is about 2 generations behind every browser when it comes to CSS.

Try using Firebug or Chrome Developer tools to check your console for javascript errors. If none are found it is definitely CSS. Post an example URL and we'll solve it for you. Without code it's hard to fix things blindly.  ;)